# Netsuite Customer Payment Template

Tags: sql, pdf, freemarker, netsuite

I need to include the value '**PO/Check Num**' from the APPLY Sublist, on the PDF template for Customer Payments. This value doesn't show up in the sublist by default, by opening up a Customer Payment in EDIT Mode, you can customize the sublist and show this column. On my other templates this value is available using the script; `${record.otherrefnum}`

I have looked in the Netsuite ScriptID guide, but have not found the right tag to include the highlighted values in screenshots attached. 
I have tried variations of `${record.apply.otherrefnum}` but no luck so far

Answer (score 0):

I just found the following in SuiteAnswers if anyone still needs this answer.  Users must customize their payment page to show the PO/Check # column for this solution to work.

Print the PO# in Customer Payment using Advanced PDF/HTML Template
Published 05/28/2021 07:35 PM   |    Updated 05/28/2021 07:35 PM   |    Answer Id: 99734
Applies To
Product:  NetSuite 2021.1

Scenario
Print the PO# field in the Customer Payment record.

Solution
Navigate to Customization > Forms > Advanced PDF/HTML Templates
Preferred Advanced PDF/HTML Template: Click Edit
Source Code: Click Toggle Switch
Add the code below:
${apply.Transaction_OTHERREFNUM}
Click Save